# How to install vinyl tubing for bathroom vent?

Tags: vent, exterior, ceiling-fan, vinyl

I need to replace the vinyl tubing that goes from my bathroom ceiling to the side of the house.

It had a rip in it and I was successful in pulling it out. I went into the attic crawl space and noticed there was a board over that area, so I am not able to get to it from that spot.

There is insulation where the vinyl tubing was. I thought about using a electric wire snake to pull it through the hole, but I want to know the best way to go about accomplishing this.

The distance is about 6 ft and it needs a 4" vinyl tubing.

First picture of the original tubing (before I ripped it)

[image]

Second image is after I removed the tubing.

[image]

Comment: Can you post a picture?

Comment: @ChrisCudmore I added two photos, I am at work right now, so I can take better photos later. There was a birds nest in it and I had to pull it out and took these photos to see what else I had to get, in the process I ripped the tubing.

Comment: Could you slide a section of rigid duct through? Why does it *have* to be vinyl?

Comment: Is that dried grass inside the old duct?

Comment: Yes, a bird made a nest in it, I was taking photos to see where the bird was since I couldn't get my head in there, I removed all of that, now I need to replace the 4" vinyl tubing.

Answer (score 1):

Make a 4" dia plug from a 1x6 or plywood, screw eyelet into center, clamp plug into dryer vent with worm gear clamp.  Pull through with your fish tape.  Perhaps a taped cone could be centered over the plug (and the fish tape lead through the center, for better insulation tracking).

Down the road this lint brush will remove any buildup.  This one has a 10ft shaft.

[image]

I'd urge you to convert to smooth walled metal duct and add a screened vent wall cover or a spring loaded damper.

Comment: what do I use the lint brush for?

Comment: @brad revised answer once I realized you'd removed all the vinyl duct, I was imagining a partial duct after the ripped section was removed.